# I can not understand Macro function`s result in C language

Tags: c

--
Hello,
I can`t understand why "#define max(a,b) (a>b)?(a):(b)" does not work that i expected.

```
#include<cstdio>
#define max(a,b) (a>b)?(a):(b)
int main(void){   
  printf("%d\n",max(3,5)); // result = 5 (work correctly)
  int a = 3 + max(3,5);
  printf("%d\n",a); // result = 3 (work incorrect and i don`t know why..)
}
```

i can`t why variable + macro does not work.

but, In this case "#define max(a,b) ((a>b)?(a):(b))"  work correctly. even that var + macro situation.

plz anybody clarify this.. thx.

Comment: Think about what the two possibilities will produce after macro expansion: `3 + (3 > 5) ? (3) : (5)` versus `3 + ((3 > 5) ? (3) : (5))`. Do you see why the additional set of parentheses matters?

Comment: i can totally understand now!! thx. it's clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have this:

```
#define max(a,b) (a>b)?(a):(b)
```

And you write this:

```
int a = 3 + max(3,5);
```

That expands to:

```
int a = 3 + (a>b)?(3):(5)
```

Because `+` has a higher [operator precendence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `?`, this is effectively:

```
int a = (3 + (a>b)) ? (3) : (5)
```

And since `3 + (a>b)` is always going to evaluate to a true-ish value, the result will always be `3`.

---

By putting the whole expansion in parentheses:

```
#define max(a,b) ((a>b)?(a):(b))
```

You get instead:

```
int a = 3 + ((a>b)?(3):(5))
```

Because the outer parentheses group the ternary operator expression, you get the result you expect.

---

Note that as @zwol writes in a comment, you should actually write your macro like:

```
#define max(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
```

The extra parentheses around `a` and `b` in `(a)>(b)` protect against exactly this sort of operator precedence problem.

Comment: Note that there should be additional parentheses around the `a` and `b` in `(a<b)`.

Answer (score 2):

Operator precedence. I get a warning with `clang`.

> ```
> test.cc:7:15: warning: operator '?:' has lower precedence than '+'; '+' will be evaluated first [-Wparentheses]
>   int a = 3 + max(3,5);
> ```

Easy to fix with parenthesis.

```
#define max(a,b) ((a>b)?(a):(b))
```